# Symfony 2 Doctrine event subscribers onFlush/PostFlush don't firing in external bundle

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I encounter a problem when I want to execute some code post doctrine Flush with a subscriber. When i'm updating an entity, my `on/post flush` functions are not executed.

I have no error (or anything else) in symfony logs, nothing in nginx/php logs even if I cause a syntax error in my event. I restarted my php and cleared my cache.

As [the symfony doc says for my symfony version (2.8)](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class) I made the following :

**MyBundle\EventSubscriber\MyEntityUpdatedEventSubscriber**

```
<?php

namespace MyBundle\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;

class MyEntityEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function __construct(MySuperService $myService)
    {
        $this->myService = $myService;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            'onFlush',
            'postFlush',
        );
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args)
    {
        $uow = $args->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
            // bla bla
        }
        //some interesting code
    }

    public function postFlush()
    {
        //Another interesting lines
    }
}
```

My service declaration looks like this :

**MyBundle/Resources/config/service.yml**

```
services:
    my_bundle.event.myentity_updated:
        class: MyBundle\EventSubscriber\MyEntityUpdatedEventSubscriber
        arguments:
            - @my_super_service
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

And to finish, my service.yml is loaded in the bundle dependency injection extension.

**MyBundle\DependencyInjection\MyBundleExtension**

```
[...]

    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
[...]
```

My question is simple : Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have subscribed to 2 events as `onFlush` and `postFlush`. If you see the document [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html), I didn't see any such events.

However I always use below events and they fill in all sort of my requirements.

```
/**
 * Hook to the events that need to be subscribed!!
 * @return array
 */
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        'prePersist',
        'postPersist',
        'preUpdate',
        'postUpdate',
        'postDelete',
    );
}
```

**One more thing**:
If your service `@my_super_service` requires `@doctrine.orm.entity_manager` as one of its argument, you might see some `infinite dependency loop`. Just mentioned as I faced it once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advice. This is the list of event fired by doctrine http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events. I need to use these events but I tried a `LifeCycle` (postUpdate) to test. It is not passing in my function at all. That sounds like symfony is not aware of my subscriber...

Comment: Can you try declaring your service configuration in `app/config/services.yml` ? Just in case, `Bundle dependency injection` is not initiating the service.

Comment: Sorry for these two weeks without response, I had a lot of things to do. I came back on the problem this morning and I just saw that I didn't declared my external bundle with the listener in my AppKernel...Sorry for the waste of time, I'll delete this question this afternoon as it's not.